# Doubt about Gluing Topological Spaces in Vakil's FOAG

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, schemes

y'all. I'm doing (trying to) FOAG on my own and in chapter 4 when Vakil do (actually, asks to) gluing schemes, he first defines how to glue topological spaces, but his definition is very different from any other books. I know that I can do the exercise 4.4A without understand his definition on how to glue topological spaces, but since I'm studying alone the notes I was not wanting to move forward without truly understand it. The definition is here (http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf) on page 141.

[image]

I'm having some trouble to understand the classes. Usually the books define the equivalence relation on points. So if anyone could shed some light I would be grateful. Just to be clear: I'm trying to understand the classes on Vakil's definition.

Comment: I think what he writes is shorthand for identifying (i.e., considering as equivalent) the corresponding points of $U$ and $V$, where the correspondence is the given homeomorphism.

Comment: Makes sense. I was not being able to do it via sets, but this doesn't mean that is not possible.

Comment: I wrote an answer with a bit more detail.  I am not sure where you are confused; if you tell me, I can try to be clearer.

Comment: It was enough, thank you. I was thinking on define it on sets, but the classes are on points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new topological space is $W$, whose points are equivalence classes of points from $X \cup Y$, each of which is either a singleton (if it is a point of $X$ not in $U$, or a point of $Y$ not in $V$) or a pair of points (a point of $U$ and the corresponding point of $V$).

The open sets of $W$ are those sets of the form an open set from $X$ union an open set from $Y$.